# alternative way for canActivate in angular

Tags: angular, state, guard, canactivate, angular-guards

In my angular 12 project, I have applied `canActivate` on routes but due to which routes are not working on browser page reload.

In `canActivate` , i am checking data is present or not in localStorage for currentUser. but when I reload page I didn't get value for localStorage item.

If I remove `canActivate` then page reload works fine.

Is there any other way in which I can prevent user for accessing routes if not logged in?

Comment: I believe you are falling into the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ?

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way to prevent the user from routing if not logged in is using [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) since it is specific to the current session. But you can also use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) depending on your scenario. So you can do it like this:

In LoginComponent:

```
login(){

 if(this.username == "username" && this.password == "password"){
      sessionStorage.setItem('login', 'loggedOn');
         this.router.navigate(['/linkyouwant']);
 }
       
}
```

In your loginGuardService:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        

        if (sessionStorage.getItem('login') == 'loggedOn')
           return true;
        else {
           this._router.navigate(['/login']);
           return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try to check for logged in in NgOnInit() and redirect user to other route

As I know that for each route goes with a component and a component got NgOnInit() of the life cycle